# Can two classical objects be correlated and tested to produce the results of Malus Law?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Of course testing one pair is not enough and I’m talking about thousands of pairs, tested at multiple set points.
To be specific the objects are 12 inch long throwing knives, one inch tall by 1/8” wide or thick.
Their correlation involves a few things such as:
(1) They are moving away from each other at the same speed and will reach the testers at the same time. 
(2) As they move toward the testers they are rotating vertically end over end.
(3) The tester/analyzers are walls with 1” wide slots that can be rotated to different set points ranging from vertical to horizontal.

Now you can see that when the slots are set vertically, all the knives will pass through.
When the slots are set horizontally, no knives can pass through.
Now when you rotate the slot five degrees from vertical you can see that the knife will most likely make it through but now there is a chance that as the knife rotates it may make contact with one of the edges of the slot. 
At the vertical set point all knives made it through and at five degrees its obvious to see that the odds have been very slightly reduced.

When you rotate the slot to twenty five degrees it becomes harder for a knife to pass but you can see that if the if the knife is rotated in the right way it will still pass.

If the set point is at 85 degrees ( not quite horizontal) most likely a knife will not pass but there is a very very slim chance that if the knife is pointed at the slot when it gets there it will go through.

After throwing thousands of knives through all the set points from vertical to horizontal you accumulate the results. 
The results will show that the number of knives passing through is directly proportionate to the set point angle.
More interesting is that the proportional results are not linear. Instead you will find that they follow Malus Law and cos2theta.

EDIT
Bell's inequalities is an attempt to prove this cannot be done.

But here we have a real situation ( not even a theory) where the results do match the predictions of quantum mechanics. They follow Malus Law perfectly.

So the question really should be why can’t two classical objects be correlated to produce these results?

Comment: Malus's Law is not the only prediction of quantum mechanics. I think you're confusing the words ***all*** and ***any***. Bell's theorem is equivalent to saying "You can't take ***all*** of the apples for yourself", meaning you can take some apples, but not all of them at once. You seem to be assuming it's something like "You can't take ***any*** of the apples for yourself", which means you can't even take one.

Comment: @probably_someone Bell’s inequalities only discusses these results. Also most other discussions claiming to disprove local realism use the same Bell inequalities that  seem to not always be true.

Comment: @probably_someone also you have to admit this is interesting considering no one else has ever demonstrated a classic derivation that matches Malus Law. Everyone said it was impossible.

Comment: @probably_someone It is Bell’s inequality that claims a local hidden variable cannot produce results equal to quantum mechanics. Even if that wasn’t Bell‘s intention every other book in the world uses his inequalities to try and prove just that. My question is pointing that out and I’m asking why can’t two classic objects be correlated to match Malus Law? If the inequalities fail as I pointed out, then why does everyone try to use them to prove entanglement and spooky action at a distanced?

Comment: @probably_someone it is clear that I have challenged Bell’s inequalities. If you want me to look at another problem please be specific